# please check the program it automatically takes the newline when i input in the console

Tags: c, function, struct, structure

thanks for the previous help

now i am facing issues with the output
it automatically takes newline \n when i input in the console as evident from the screenshot i am attaching

please identify the issues

**PS: if anyone could tell me what is "stdin" i would be really greatful**
**NOTE: i just updated the code please have a look**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void input();
void output();

struct book
{
  char title[70],id[70],aname[70],price[5];

}b1,b2;

void main()
{
  input();
  output();
}

void input()
{
  int i;
  char t[70],in[70],p[5],an[70];

  for(i=1;i<3;++i)
  {
    printf("type the ID for book %d:",i);
    fgets(in,70,stdin);

    printf("type the title for book %d:",i);
    fgets(t,70,stdin);

    printf("type the author name for book %d:",i);
    fgets(an,70,stdin);

    printf("type the price for book %d:",i);
    fgets(p,5,stdin);

    printf("\n");

    if(i==1)
    {
      strcpy(b1.id,in);
      strcpy(b1.title,t);
      strcpy(b1.aname,an);
      strcpy(b1.price,p);
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
      strcpy(b2.id,in);
      strcpy(b2.title,t);
      strcpy(b2.aname,an);
      strcpy(b2.price,p);
    }
   
  }

}

void output()
{
  printf("Sr.No.\t\tID\t\tTITLE\t\tAUTHOR NAME\t\tPRICE\n");

  for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
  {
    if(i==1)
    {
      printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t",i,b1.id,b1.title,b1.aname,b1.price);
      printf("\n");
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
      printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t",i,b2.id,b2.title,b2.aname,b2.price);
      printf("\n");
    }
    
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhU3q.png)

Comment: You are calling the functions  input() and output() without specifying arguments;.

Comment: Almost certainly, `gets(p);` will be damaging.

Comment: If you type more than 4 characters for the price, all hell will break loose.  `gets()` doesn't know that you only allocated `char p[5]`, and there's no way for you to tell it.  And this is why `gets()` has been removed from the language, because it's not possible to use it safely.

Comment: requesting for help with the updated program

Comment: if someone could please tell me what stdin is i would be greatful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by not matching arguments in function declaration and function call.

You should remove the not passed and harmful (shadowing global variables) arguments from the function definition.

Also you should add headers and declarations of function to use before points where the functions are used.

```c
/* add headers */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book
{
  char title[70],id[70],aname[70],price[5];

}b1,b2,b3;

/* add declarations of functiosn to use */
void input(void);
void output(void);

int main(void) /* use standard signature of main() */
{
  input();
  output();
  return 0;
}

void input(void) /* remove arguments */
{
  int i;
  char t[70],in[70],p[5],an[70];

  for(i=1;i<=3;++i)
  {
    printf("type the ID for book %d:",i);
    gets(in);

    printf("type the title for book %d:",i);
    gets(t);

    printf("type the author name for book %d:",i);
    gets(an);

    printf("type the price for book %d:",i);
    gets(p);

    if(i==1)
    {
      strcpy(b1.id,in);
      strcpy(b1.title,t);
      strcpy(b1.aname,an);
      strcpy(b1.price,p);
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
      strcpy(b2.id,in);
      strcpy(b2.title,t);
      strcpy(b2.aname,an);
      strcpy(b2.price,p);
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {
      strcpy(b3.id,in);
      strcpy(b3.title,t);
      strcpy(b3.aname,an);
      strcpy(b3.price,p);
    }
    
  }
  in[i]='\0';
  t[i]='\0';
  an[i]='\0';
  p[i]='\0';
}

void output(void) /* remove arguments */
{
  printf("Sr.No.\t\tID\t\tTITLE\t\tAUTHOR NAME\t\tPRICE\n");

  for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
  {
    if(i==1)
    {
      printf("%d\t\t",i);
      printf("%s\t\t",b1.id);
      printf("%s\t\t",b1.title);
      printf("%s\t\t",b1.aname);
      printf("%s\t\t",b1.price);
      printf("\n");
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
      printf("%d\t\t",i);
      printf("%s\t\t",b2.id);
      printf("%s\t\t",b2.title);
      printf("%s\t\t",b2.aname);
      printf("%s\t\t",b2.price);
      printf("\n");
    }
    if(i==3)
    {
      printf("%d\t\t",i);
      printf("%s\t\t",b3.id);
      printf("%s\t\t",b3.title);
      printf("%s\t\t",b3.aname);
      printf("%s\t\t",b3.price);
      printf("\n");
    }
   
  }
}
```

The next step will be stop using `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11. Using `fgets()` and removing newline characters in the buffer (`strtok()` with the delimiter `"\n"` is useful) will be the alternative.